# Android Camera Issue (Device Specific)

Tags: android, camera

Following is the code, where I am trying to open Android Default Camera directly. It works fine with most of the devices and opens the Default Camera without creating a Chooser if another camera app is installed.

```
 private void callTheCamera(){

        String pkgName = "";
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

        for (ApplicationInfo ai: installedApps) {

            if ((ai.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
                // System app - do something here
                if(ai.toString().toLowerCase().contains("camera")){
                    pkgName = ai.packageName;
                }
            } else {
                // User installed app?
            }
        }

        if(!pkgName.equals("")){
            try {
                Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                LaunchIntent.setPackage(pkgName);
                LaunchIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(LaunchIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                LaunchIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(LaunchIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
        else{
            Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            LaunchIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
            startActivityForResult(LaunchIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

However, the App crashes in few devices with the following issue:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE pkg=com.sonymobile.android.addoncamera.timeshift (has extras) }
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1638)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1430)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3457)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3418)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:784)
       at com.goldvip.crownit.BasicCameraActivity.callTheCamera(SourceFile:674)
       at com.goldvip.crownit.BasicCameraActivity.access$000(SourceFile:60)
       at com.goldvip.crownit.BasicCameraActivity$2.run(SourceFile:136)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Now, how to tackle this efficiently.??

Comment: Its scattered between Android OS 4,5 &6...

Comment: what is setImageUri(). ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the exception seems pretty clear to me:

> No Activity found to handle Intent {
>   act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE

In your code, you suppose that if there's a system app having `camera` in its package name somewhere, that app must be able to handle the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent. But obviously (as the Exception tells you) that is *not always the case*.

You might need to just catch that `ActivityNotFoundException` and try user installed apps in that case or as a final resort tell the user you cannot take a picture. There are Android devices out there without a camera, you know.

Also I think that there are better ways to find apps that can perform certain Intents, than to simply check their package name.